# Не выводит второй блок

Tags: python, while

```
s = input()
i = 0
while i != len(s):
    if s[i] == "a" or s[i]=="e":
        print('Ага! Нашлась')
        break
    else:
        print("Текущая буква:",s[i])
        i +=1
    if  len(s) - 1 == 0:
        print("Распечатали все буквы")
```

Comment: Блоки менял местами, ничего не помогает(

Comment: Что есть "второй блок"?

Comment: Ваш код выполняет следующую функцию: Если в `s` есть 'a' или 'e' то печатаем 'нашлась ' Если нет то текущую букву. Какого результата вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: `if  len(s) - 1 == i:`

Answer (score 1):

Что за конструкция `len(s) - 1 == 0`, которая будет срабатывать только для строки состоящей из одного символа, я не понял. Но, наверное, имелось ввиду что-то вроде этого:

```
s = input()
i = 0
while i != len(s):
    if s[i] == "a" or s[i]=="e":
        print('Ага! Нашлась')
        break
    else:
        print("Текущая буква:", s[i])
    i +=1
else:
    print("Распечатали все буквы")
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! понял как много мне еще нужно учить в программировании)

Answer (score 0):

Если есть несколько условий, нужно использовать elif
Код будет выглядеть так:

```
s = input()
i = 0
while i != len(s):
    if s[i] == "a" or s[i] == "e":
        print('Ага! Нашлась')
        break
    elif  len(s) - 1 == 0:
        print("Распечатали все буквы")
    else:
        print("Текущая буква:", s[i])
        i += 1
```

Comment: elif  не работает(

Comment: еще раз проверила, код, который я выложила рабочий. Скопируйте его. Проверьте в какой строке ошибка и какая

Comment: Текущая буква: Q
Текущая буква: W
Текущая буква: E
Текущая буква: R
Текущая буква: T
Текущая буква: Y

Comment: при таких данных не выводит последнее условие) а так код рабочий) спасибо за посощь)